# Basemap lat/long boundary setting

Tags: python, latitude-longitude, matplotlib-basemap, boundary

I'd like to set the ticks for latitude and longitude (black and white blocks)  [like those seen here](http://mygeologypage.ucdavis.edu/gps/GMT/CALIFORNIA/map.html). Unfortunately I've not been able to locate the correct Basemap command. Could someone proficient in Basemap point me in the right direction?

Comment: See here: http://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/graticule.html

Comment: Thanks, though the link doesn't explain the black-white blocks as seen in my link. This is possible with GMT.

Comment: I see! You mean the boundaries strip in `zebra` style. I often this boundary setting in figure produced by __GMT__. In my humble opinion,  this kind of boundaries don't have any true meaning and may confuse reader when __plotting scale bar__ also exist.

Comment: But I have one indirect method to generate the zebra stripe using `matplotlib.basemap.patches`. By carefully define the corner for each rectangle, there should be a similar figure.

Comment: Yes Zebra style, exactly. It's just purely for aesthetics (many maps shown on publications I read also use the same format).